# What certificate does a windows driver use for signing

Tags: windows, drivers

How do I find out which certificate a windows driver uses for signature verification? I'm looking at `usbhub.sys` in particular (official windows driver).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on `usbhub.sys` file, seclect Properties, then Digital Signatures, then Details and finally View Certificate.

Comment: If the tab doesn't exist does this mean the driver is not signed (not just that the signature cannot be verified)? Actually I don't think this works for `usbhub.sys`, the digital signatures tab isn't there.

Comment: Not tab - no signature at all. Verification process is a different thing. However, usbhub.sys in my win8.1 is signed.

Comment: It's signed in my windows 7 vm as well (under device management) but that only gives a vague description of "Microsoft Windows" as the signer, I don't see any digital signatures tab for some reason.

Comment: Checked Win7 VM, same result, file is not signed, however Device Manager show me that the signer is Microsoft Windows. Some other drivers are signed with Microsoft Windows and Digital Signature is visible in the driver file properties.

Comment: A [catalog file signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537872(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used as a signature for a collection of the files.

Comment: I did find a bunch of those under `C:\Windows\System32\catroot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}` and used grep to find those which contained the string "usbhub.sys", but there must be a better way?

Comment: Not sure about bettwr way. Maybe [signature verifier code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384.aspx) or [signature check via signtool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388171(v=vs.85).aspx) can answer some questions?